# How do I use a for loop to extract loans with loan_price under 500?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

```py
#list of loans
loans = [
    {
        "loan_price": 700,
        "remaining_months": 9,
        "repayment_interval": "monthly",
        "future_value": 1000,
    },
    {
        "loan_price": 500,
        "remaining_months": 13,
        "repayment_interval": "bullet",
        "future_value": 1000,
    },
    {
        "loan_price": 200,
        "remaining_months": 16,
        "repayment_interval": "bullet",
        "future_value": 1000,
    },
    {
        "loan_price": 900,
        "remaining_months": 16,
        "repayment_interval": "bullet",
        "future_value": 1000,
    },
]


#empty dictionary
inexpensive_loans = []

loan_price = loans.get(loans[loan_price])

for loan_price in loans:
    if loans[loan_price] <= 500:
        inexpensive_loans.append(loans[loan_price])

print(inexpensive_loans)
```

I want to extract the loans where the loan_price is under 500 and put them into `inexpensive_loans`.

Comment: What should `inexpensive_loans` contain? A list of dicts of inexpensive loans, or just the prices?

Answer (score 0):

`loans` is a `list`, it doesn't have `.get` method. To get all prices <= 500 you can use a list comprehension:

```py
inexpensive_loans = [
    loan["loan_price"] for loan in loans if loan["loan_price"] <= 500
]

print(inexpensive_loans)
```

Prints:

```
[500, 200]
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the whole dictionary appended. `inexpensive_loans = [
    loan for loan in loans if loan["loan_price"] <= 500
]` or maybe I misread?